# Angular: How would you create a text in the template, which iterates visibly over an array of strings?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an Angular 16 Project.
I need to change a word in a sentence, so it changes all the time and displays another word every tenth of a second.

In JS I would have done this:

```
let jobs = ["wordOne", "wordTwo", "wordThree", "wordFour", "wordFive"]
var elem = document.getElementById("ito");
var elem2 = document.getElementById("ito2");
var counter = 0;
setInterval(change, 100);

function change() {
    elem.innerHTML = jobs[counter];
    elem2.innerHTML = jobs[counter];
       counter++;
       if(counter >= jobs.length) { counter = 0; }
   }
```

But in Angular I don't seem to be able to get the change detection do the same. I even tried putting this code in a pipe, but it won't update the word at all.
I used a solution, where I just made a sentence, and gave it a marker in place where the word needs to be replaced (++replaced++).

"This is an example entsence, which contains ++replaced++ words."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use rxjs and the async pipe.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [AsyncPipe],
  template: `{{ job$ | async }}`,
})
export class App {
  private readonly jobs = [
    'wordOne',
    'wordTwo',
    'wordThree',
    'wordFour',
    'wordFive',
  ];
  protected job$ = interval(100).pipe(
    map((i) => this.jobs[i % this.jobs.length])
  );
}
```

See stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1yjn8u?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: Merci und Servus!